# package prefix meaning

Tags: crates

I noticed that a lot of low level packages used by substrate have names that are prefixed with “sc, sp, fc” etc, I’m wondering what the meanings are for these prefixes. For example sp-std, sc-consensus, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `sc_*` - Substrate Client Crates (`./substrate/client/`)
- `sp_*` - Substrate Primitives Crates (`./substrate/primitives/`)
- `frame_*` - Substrate FRAME Crates (`./substrate/frame/`)
- `pallet_*` - Substrate Pallet Crates, made with FRAME (`./substrate/frame/`)

There is no `fc` as far as I can see, so not sure what you mean there.

Comment: That make sense now, thanks! The fc- packages I was seeing are part of the frontier template’s client folder, so I guess it stands for “frontier client”, thanks!